# Selenium, Python - Selecting a value from a dropdown based on variable

Tags: python, selenium

Morning all. I'm currently working on trying to select a country from a dropdown menu based on a dictionary value. I was trying to use sendkeys(), and quickly ran into errors with that when sending "United States" kept returning "United Arab Emerates". I then found .select_by_values", but that doesn't seem to be working. I have the following imports:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as UI
    import unittest, time, re, datetime
```

And the following is my select:

```
d.find_element_by_css_selector('select#residenceQuestion').select_by_value(quote_data["citizenship"])
```

When run however, I'm met with the Attribute error "'WebElement' object has no attribute 'select_by_value'". It could very well be that I'm either locating the dropdown incorrectly (because it is, indeed, returning as a WebElement), or using select_by wrong. Any help's appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to use `Select` functionality.  I think this will work for you:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

Select(d.find_element_by_css_selector('select#residenceQuestion')).select_by_value(quote_data["citizenship"])
```

Comment: @TRoch You're right, an import is required.  See my edit.  Also, it seems I had the syntax slightly wrong.

Comment: Scratch that! I had the import right, it was the order in the select statement--got it :). Now the select is working, now it's just getting the actual selection right. should've been:

`Select(d.find_element_by_css_selector('select#residenceQuestion')).select_by_value(quote_data["citizenship"])`

Thanks mate!